# Uninstall Python 3.4.3 from Windows 10 (not replace)

Tags: python, uninstallation

I installed Python 3.4.3 a while ago for a Python workshop, but I never use it and want to uninstall it.  Whenever I try to uninstall it I get a message that says "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

I did see a couple similar questions on here with the same message, but all of them had to do with wanting to install a DIFFERENT version of Python and all the answers just told them to run them simultaneously.  I just want this uninstalled with no other version to replace it. Please help?

Comment: Re-download the installer for Python 3.4.3 and choose the uninstall object when you run it. This isn't really the correct format for a question on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.  What is the correct format? I don't post very often.

Comment: Due to the way this site is now organized, you will notice is most of the new questions that a "correct" question is extremely detailed and very specific in scope almost invariably referring to specific problem in a code snippet provided by the asker - not just the practice of Computer Science or programming. There are other sites within the stackechange network that prefer more broad computing questions, they would be better for this type of question.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification!